# Angular JS with EJStreegrid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, treegrid

We need to validate the value entered in a column which is named as `Non run time hours`. Validation logic is done on the server side and a record is returned from the backend when the validation fails. But instead of throwing the error message, we need to highlight the cell.

Could some one suggest how to highlight the cell in UI (`Angular JS with treegrid`) once validation failed in server side?